# Scrolling bar inside another scrolling bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

Very briefly , i am importing photos from a facebook page and present them to my `jquery mobile webpage` , using the photoSwipe plugin.

The problem is that the final result looks a bit strange. Look at this photo where the red arrow points at..

[image]

As you can see for a reason i get 2 scrolling bars instead of one.. When i view it from the mobile phone though , it seems like one bar.

In the example code of *PhotoSwipe plugin* the scrolling bar looks ok:

[image]

I wont give any code for now , as i want to find the error by myself. I just need some help on what to look for. In theory what might cause this double scroll bar effect? What exactly does it mean to have 2 scroll bars like this? The inner scroll bar , just scrolls some millimeters.. The outer one works as expected and scrolls through all the photos.

### EDIT (BASED ON THE ANSWERS)

---

This is how i dynamically create the galleries :

```
$("#Home").after('<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id=Gallery'+ i +
               ' class="gallery-page"' + ' data-url="Gallery' + i + '"> ' +
               ' <div data-role="header"><h1>Gallery</h1></div> ' + ' <div data-role="content"> ' +
               ' <ul class="gallery"></ul> ' + ' </div> ' +
               ' </div> ');
```

How can i add the `overflow:hidden` attribute here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the PhotoSwipe plugin and was able to exactly replicate your issue when changed the `overflow: hidden` to `overflow: auto` in `jquery-mobile.css` line no `6` i.e. `#Gallery1 .ui-content, #Gallery2 .ui-content`.

#### Edit: Adding Solution Here

So, instead add the following line to your CSS:

```
.gallery-page .ui-content{overflow:hidden;}
```

This will take care of all the galleries that you are adding dynamically.

Comment: It is set to hidden , the problem is that is only for the 2 galleries(gallery1 and gallery2). I dynamically import albums so i have many galleries. How can i hide it in every gallery? I ll show you in my question how i create the galleries.

Comment: So, instead add the following line to your CSS: 

    `.gallery-page .ui-content{overflow:hidden;}`

This will take care of all the galleries that you are adding dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have a scroll bar on the body and the html elements. Or on the body and the div where the photo's are in.

Disable scrolling on one of those elements by using: overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: auto;

Do it one by one and you'll eliminate the unwanted scrollbar.

Comment: Answer stays the same, no matter how you add the gallery to your page. Read it carefully, disable scroll on the three elements one by one and you'll see which one causes the double scroll. My best guess it's the html or body element.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you have the `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: scroll;` property set on a container `DIV` that contains the entire layout or on the `BODY` tag.